# Easies way of compiling simple windows binary

Tags: c++, c

as I failed the third time now maybe someone of you can answer me this (easy?) question.

I'm searching for the easiest way to create a exe binary containing just some lines of C/C++ (or anything else) code and do NOT depend on any dll's that are not available on every Windows system. So no cygwin dlls, no .NET Redistributables, and working from XP->Windows 10. The filesize should be as small as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: That's hard !!!   :)

Comment: There's an option in just about all linker (and also in IDEs) that tells the linker to not link with any standard libraries. You can then manually add the libraries needed for the native WIN32 API. The drawback is that you can't use any CRT or standard C or C++ functionality, only pure WIN32 API functions. Will it make your executable smaller? Yes. Will it be noticeable? Barely. Why won't it be barely noticeable? Because most of the stuff is in DLLs anyway, and not in your executable file. Do I recommend it? No, not really.

Comment: "No DLLs" does not live in the same city as "as small as possible".

Comment: I think you misunderstood the idea of DLL. The idea is to load library at a runtime, so if you decide to use framework that is based on DLLs you need to keep this convention.

Comment: thanks for all the downvotes. Maybe my question wasn't exact enough. With try-and-error of different compiling software I found something suitable, MinGW offers a small-footprint dll. Thanks for your answers though. So my on-line-executable is 250kb, thats ok for me.

Comment: Obligatory troll post of some guys trying to get the smallest exe size by using ASM: http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=13682

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't care much about filesize but about not depending on third-party DLLs? Then you can always link libraries statically (of course you need to have them as an archive named like *lib<name>.a* available). For example, I use the following for my windows build of a game using the *pdcurses* library:

```
csnake_win32_LDFLAGS:= -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lpdcurses \
    -Wl,-Bdynamic -lwinmm
```

This is just added to the flags to `gcc` in the linking stage by my Makefile when compiling for windows.

`-static-libgcc` is probably the most important because *libgcc* is (almost) always needed and automatically linked ... and the default is to link it dynamically.

`-Wl` passes an option from `gcc` to the linker (`ld`). `-Bstatic` tells the linker the following libs should be statically linked. I'm switching back here to dynamic linking because `winmm.dll` is a windows system dll.

Answer (score 1):

You need Win32 API (no MFC). You can use Visual C++ Express for example. It is important to enable "Multi threaded" for Runtime Library (without DLL). This is in C++/Code Generation settings. With older compiler like VC 6 or Borland C++ 5 your exe will run without problems on all Windows from Windows 95 and above.

Comment: nice idea, I may try this :)